# Traverse JSON data structure into tree in java

Tags: java, json

I need to build a tree from JSON. The JSON structure reads, for every restProjectLevel : restProjectLevels I have an id = level were on. A sequenceNr = root or child. For every restProject : restProjects I have an id = projectId and a projectIdHook = the projectId that's attached.

I think the JSON data will explan it best.

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "description": "New Project Plan",
    "restProjectLevels": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "sequenceNr": 0,
            "restProjects": [
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "projectName": "Project A",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 19,
                    "projectIdHook": 0,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 29,
                    "projectName": "Project B",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 19,
                    "projectIdHook": 0,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 30,
                    "projectName": "Project C",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 19,
                    "projectIdHook": 0,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 41,
                    "projectName": "New",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 19,
                    "projectIdHook": 0,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "sequenceNr": 1,
            "restProjects": [
                {
                    "id": 31,
                    "projectName": "Project A.1",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 20,
                    "projectIdHook": 28,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 33,
                    "projectName": "Project B.1",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 20,
                    "projectIdHook": 29,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 35,
                    "projectName": "Project C.1",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 20,
                    "projectIdHook": 30,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "sequenceNr": 2,
            "restProjects": [
                {
                    "id": 32,
                    "projectName": "Project A.2",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 21,
                    "projectIdHook": 31,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 36,
                    "projectName": "Project C.2",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 21,
                    "projectIdHook": 35,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "sequenceNr": 3,
            "restProjects": [
                {
                    "id": 34,
                    "projectName": "Projet B.4",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 22,
                    "projectIdHook": 33,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "projectName": "Project C.3",
                    "description": "",
                    "projectLevelId": 22,
                    "projectIdHook": 36,
                    "restProjectProcesses": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "sequenceNr": 4,
            "restProjects": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use a JSON mapping library such as Jackson, it will create a POJO automatically out of your JSON.

Comment: I need some help to write the code. Kind regards.

Comment: #fge I have the POJO's

Comment: #fge Sorry will this also input the data if using JSON mapping lib?

Comment: OK Solved this! Not the most elegant solution but it works... Thanks!

Comment: If you've solved the problem yourself, please put the solution into an answer and mark the answer as accepted.  (It's OK to answer your own question.)  Don't put the solution into the question area and write "solved" in the title.

Comment: #Wyzard I can't answer my own question. Something to do with my status.

Comment: From the Man himself: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Comment: I agree with @fge, don't re-invent the wheel yourself. You probably won't do it correct, do it as well, and/or it won't be extendable in the future. Use a solid JSON library for Java.

Answer (score 0):

OK Solved this! Not the most elegant solution but it works...

```
    for(RestProjectLevel projectLevel: projectLevelList) {
        if(projectLevel.getSequenceNr() == 0) {
            for(RestProject project : projectLevel.getRestProjects()) {
                restParentNode = new RestParentNode();
                traverse(sortedRestProjects, project, restParentNode);
                restTree.nodes.add(restParentNode);
            }
        }
    }

private void traverse(List<RestProject> restProjects, RestProject project, RestParentNode restParentNode) {
    for (RestProject restProject : restProjects) {
        if(project.getId() == restProject.getProjectIdHook() || project.getId() == restProject.getId()) {

            String projectName = restProject.getProjectName();

            if(hasNode(projectName)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                RestNode restNode = new RestNode();
                restNode.nodes.add(restProject);
                restParentNode.nodes.add(restNode);
                traverse(restProjects, restProject, restParentNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!